# How can I enable Token recognation in Method signature in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, format, resharper

How can I supply a Method that highlights the Tokens of the formatstring when calling? Tried copying the full class signature but without success. Saw that frameworks like log4net did it somehow but I don't know how :(

Any Ideas?

EDIT : Maybe my Resharper is the source for this? Any known issues?

[image]

```
 public void Test()
    {
        string.Format("{0} - {1}", "Ahhh", "Good Highlight");
        this.MyFormat("{0} - {1}", "Why no", "Highlight?");
    }

    public string MyFormat(string format, object arg0, object arg1)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce, both look the same in my instance of VS2015 (they highlight like the second example). Why is your string.format underlined your example?

Comment: The underline comes because I don't use the returnvalue of string.Format in any way. I guess that's a resharper hint. May this be the source of evil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with [ReSharper Annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Analysis__Code_Annotations.html). You need to mark your `MyFormat` method with a [`StringFormatMethodAttribute`](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Analysis__String_Formatting_Methods.html#custom) for this to work:

```
[StringFormatMethod("format")]
public string MyFormat(string format, object arg0, object arg1)
{
    return string.Empty;
}
```

This will make ReSharper treat your method with the same highlighting features.

Last year I recorded a webinar with JetBrains called [ReSharper Secrets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tpza_xVaIg), where I explain annotations in much greater detail, please watch it if you like to know more.

Comment: Thanks in advance. I will test this on monday :)